# Launch a PowerShell command and then pass it a password

Tags: vb.net, powershell

I wrote a small .NET program to run a PowerShell command.

```
 Process.Start("powershell", "-noexit runas /u:FL-LOCAL\UserName notepad.exe")
```

After the script loads PowerShell then asks for a password (which is what I want to happen).  How can I then pass that in using .NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to redirect the standard input (i.e. STDIN) so that you can write directly to it from your application:

```
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo("powershell", "-noexit runas /u:FL-LOCAL\UserName notepad.exe") With
{
    .RedirectStandardInput = True,
    .RedirectStandardOutput = False,
    .UseShellExecute = False
}
Dim p As New Process With
{ 
    .StartInfo = psi 
}
p.Start()
p.StandardInput.WriteLine(password)
```

Comment: I've tried this for 'scp' command from windows to raspberry, I send the scp command through p.StandardInput.WriteLine(command), and powershell recieves it.
But then passing the password in the same way does nothing.... Is there something I'm missing in this answer?